# use mediapipe with tensorflow model（DTLN denoise）?

Tags: tensorflow, audio, mediapipe

I want to use mediapipe to run denoising of real-time audio (I already have a model trained with tesonrflow), there is no video input, just audio. I didn't find a relevant use case, but is this theoretically possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are many way todo but the concept is still working when you transform and re-re-transform they also removed of noises and return the function values.

**[ Sample ]:**

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Logicals
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=1, rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
file = tf.io.read_file("F:\\temp\\Python\\Speech\\Piano\\Berklee44v4\\prep_pianoE0_1.wav")
decoded_wav = tfio.audio.decode_wav( file, shape=None, dtype=tf.int16, name="decoded_wav" )
decoded_wav = tf.squeeze(decoded_wav, axis=-1)
decoded_wav_float = tf.cast( decoded_wav, dtype=tf.float32 )

print( decoded_wav )
stft = tf.signal.stft(decoded_wav_float, frame_length=256, frame_step=64)
stft = tf.abs(stft)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(decoded_wav, lw=0.5)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.grid(False)
plt.xlabel( "Spectrogram", fontsize=22 )

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.plot(stft, lw=0.5)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.grid(False)
plt.xlabel( "stft", fontsize=22 )

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: Is it feasible to use google's mediapipe（https://github.com/google/mediapipe） project to integrate

Comment: Thank you, that is a nice API and method. I sample how we doing it in telecommunications.

Comment: This totally ignores the question. 1) No mediapipe, 2) No demonstration of noise removal 3) Reads a file, so is not "real time"